# Can GlobalMapper open Personal Grodatabase (MDB( without ArcGID license?

Tags: personal-geodatabase, global-mapper

I am wondering if GlobalMapper can read an .mdb geodatabase without an ESRI license?  I have encountered some apps that can not read a .gdb without the license but can read an .mdb, so wondering if GlobalMapper is one of them.

I don't have the software to test it out, and if I download it I have an active ESRI license so can't test it out, and have not been able to find any info on the GLobalMapper support pages or user forum.

Comment: Qgis is free, try the 32bit version to read a personal geodatabase.

Comment: https://www.bluemarblegeo.com/products/global-mapper-formats.php (requires license for all Esri geodatabase formats)